# Burninate [buying]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination

I noticed we had a tag [buying](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buying) that is only used on 8 questions. It is most commonly used for questions related to buying fonts, but is also used on some software and hardware recommendation questions.

In my opinion, the tags [font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font), [hardware-recommendation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation), and [software-recommendations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) cover the topic of buying well enough to not warrant an entire tag for it.

Should we burn [buying](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buying)?

Comment: +1 because I think we should burninate it

Comment: I think we should burminate burmination :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed this tag from all 8 questions and cleaned up the questions while doing so. The tag should be burned by the system in a few days.